# How Android handles the physical hardware button press from kernel space to user space

Tags: android, embedded-linux

I want to understand how a button press on your phone (power/volume) is handled in Android and what is the flow of events that make it happen from kernel space to user space.

The requirement is that I just ported Android to a hardware and this hardware has just one button. I want to map this button for screen lock (make it act as power button)

Can anyone please give a brief overview or guidance?

Comment: I just found that there is a `.kl` file in `/system/etc` where the key mappings are done. Also, we can first check whether the kernel is reporting events from the button by using command `getevent`. If there are no logs on pressing the button, look into kernel, else do the mappings in above file and check.

Still this does not answer the original question

Answer (score 0):

The inputs is managed by `InputManager`. The kernel export some devices in `/dev/input`.
I suggest you start the learn from `http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/native/services/inputflinger/EventHub.cpp`. To capture a running android device's `/dev/input` IO would also be helpful.